# Why is three-argument open calls with autovivified filehandles a Perl best practice?

Tags: perl, file-io, scope

I've got two questions about the Perl `open` function:

1) I seem to remember from *Perl Best Practices* that the 3-argument version of `open` is better than the two argument version, e.g.

```
open(OUT, '>>', $file);
```

vs.

```
open(OUT, ">>$file");
```

Why is that? I was trying to tell somebody to use the 3-argument version the other day but couldn't seem to back it up with anything.

2) I also seem to remember autovivified  filehandles being favored over bareword filehandles (they called something different)? And also couldn't remember why, e.g.

```
open(my $out, '>>', $file);
```

vs.

```
open(OUT, '>>', $file);
```

Is it a `strict` thing? I seem to remember being able to use `OUT` with `strict` but I can't remember.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318789/whats-the-best-way-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-perl

Comment: It's because Perl::Critic advices this :)

Comment: Not a dupe, this is asking why it is the best way to do that.

Comment: Sorry for the edits...I'd never heard these called "autovivified filehandles" (I've always heard "lexical filehandle") and was trying to improve searchability, but now I see autovivification really is involved and the docs do refer to them that way. Rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

- Using typeglobs for filehandles (like `OUT`) is not a good idea, as they are global across your entire program - you need to be sure that no other routine including those in modules are using the same name (including in the future).
- Using the two-argument form of open exposes your application to mis-behaviour caused by variables containing special characters, for example `my $f; open $f, ">$some_filename";` is exposed to the bug where `$some_filename` containing a leading `>` will change the program's behaviour.

Using the three-argument form avoids this by separating the mode and filename into separate arguments where they can't interfere.

Moreover, using the lots-of-arguments form with pipes is a very good idea:

```
open $pipe, '|-', 'sendmail', 'fred@somewhere.fake';
```

Is better than doing it all as a single string – it avoids possible shell injection etc.

Comment: Thanks MarkR.  That was pretty much EXACTLY the set of answers I was looking for.  Glad to know there is actually a legitimate reason for me having it done it that way for the last few years.

Comment: Notes on compatibility: 3-arg open and `open my $fh, ...` work beginning in 5.6.0. `open my $fh, '|-', LIST` (list pipe open) works beginning in 5.8.0.

Comment: There is no reason to use the ugly form of pipe-open on literals of known content, such as the one suggested. Furthermore, you break shell handling of complex pipelines. Bad bad bad.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that _autovivified filehandles_ are way easier to pass as arguments to methods and subroutines. You can even open a file in a subroutine, and pass the file handle back to the caller.

Answer (score 16):

Tackling #2:

`OUT` is a global filehandle and using it exposes you to insidious bugs like this:

```
sub doSomething {
  my ($input) = @_;
  # let's compare $input to something we read from another file
  open(F, "<", $anotherFile);
  @F = <F>; 
  close F;
  &do_some_comparison($input, @F);
}

open(F, "<", $myfile);
while (<F>) {
    &doSomething($_);   # do'h -- just closed the F filehandle
}
close F;
```

Comment: Ahh, that's a very solid piece of reasoning.

Answer (score 13):

One aspect to keep in mind is that the two-arg form is broken. Consider a file named ' abc' (that is, a file name with a leading blank). You cannot open the file:

```
open my $foo, ' abc' or die $!;
open my $foo, '< abc' or die $!;
open my $foo, '<  abc' or die $!;
# nothing works
```

The space gets dropped and so the file can no longer be found. Such a scenario is highly improbable, but definitely a problem. The three-arg form is immune to this:

```
open my $foo, '<', ' abc' or die $!;
# works
```

[This thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=131085) from perlmonks is as good a discussion as any of the issue. Just bear in mind that in 2001, the three-arg form was still considered *new*, and thus not suitable for portable code, since Perl programs would die with a syntax error if run on a 5.005 interpreter. This is no longer the case: perl 5.005 is beyond deprecated, it is obsolete.

Comment: No, the two-argument form of open, or the one-argument form for that matter, is *not* broken. It is working as designed, documented, and advertised. It simply may be that *magic open* isn't what you need. Another plug for three-argument open is that the middle argument can — and often should — include the stream's encoding.