# How can I write XML data to a file with Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

Could you please correct my code below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

open (MYFILE, '>>data.xml');
print MYFILE "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n";
close (MYFILE);
```

Updated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, '>>data.xml');
print MYFILE '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>'."\n";
print MYFILE '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?\>'."\n";
close (MYFILE);
```

output:  working well now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?\>
```

BUT.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, '>>data.xml');
print MYFILE '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>'.'\n';
print MYFILE '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?\>'.'\n';
close (MYFILE);
```

Output:  # error format with \n

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?\>\n
```

Comment: I am newbie. A lot of good suggestion inputed!. I would like to try one by one. thank you all.

Comment: Like I said in a comment below, if you put \n in single quotes, it will print out two characters rather than a newline.

Comment: If you are a newbie I would also recommed always to do 'use strict'. Put this line just after the line containing "#!".

Comment: You do realize you are opening `data.xml` in append mode and then appending to it something that should be the first line of that file, **right**?

Comment: @Sinan: It's a simple test script only. YES. I would like to run my perl script at append mode. Convert my source TXT file to destination XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print MYFILE qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n};
```

Your problem is that you had nested double quotes; using `qq{}` to delimit the string will solve this issue.

Comment: @ennuikiller: You do realize you can use `qq`, I hope.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you have unescaped quotes in the string. Either escape the quotes using the backslash or surround your print string with qq{}:

```
print MYFILE qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n};
--or--
print MYFILE "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

**Always** turn on warnings and strictures, so you find out earlier what went wrong, and get more details why:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Always use the lexical-variabled, three-argument form of `open` (there's a [big discussion why over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice)), and always check the return value (it will return an error if something went wrong, and put the reason why in the [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!) variable ([see under `$!` at perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!)). Also, `die` will print the line number of where the program quit if you don't end your string with a `\n` (more at [perldoc -f die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)).

```
open my $file, '>>', 'data.xml' or die "Can't open file: $!";
```

And use double-quotes around the `\n` so that it is printed properly:

```
print $file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
print $file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>' . "\n";
close $file;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use:

```
use XML::Simple;
```

Comment: @Jay: Could you post a simple example using `XML::Simple`?

Comment: @Zaid: There are numerous tutorials online, here is one of the good ones: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlperl1.html

Comment: XML::Writer is another pretty straightforward one

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code of mine for printing an XML file:

```
open(XML, ">$xmlfile");
print XML (<<EOF);
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
 version="1.1"
 creator="Navaid Waypoint Generator - http://navaid.com/GPX/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
 xmlns:navaid="http://navaid.com/GPX/NAVAID/1/0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd
 http://navaid.com/GPX/NAVAID/1/0 http://navaid.com/GPX/NAVAID/1/0">
 <metadata>
    <author>
        <name>Paul Tomblin</name>
        <email id="ptomblin" domain="xcski.com"/>
        <link href="http://blog.xcski.com/"/>
    </author>
    <link href="http://navaid.com/GPX/"/>
</metadata>
EOF
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  It illustrates that you can avoid the quoting problems by using a here document.  If you think I'm somehow pimping my *free* software site, I can take out the references to it if you like, but it's not like I'm going to reach the expected audience (pilots) by posting it on a programming site.

Comment: Downvote by other guest. I just run the script above. it is working now. i also agree with that it is a good way to avoid the quoting problems... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Always, always, **ALWAYS** check the value returned from `open`, *e.g.*,

```
open (MYFILE, '>>data.xml')
  or die "$0: open: $!";
```

Note the important bits in the error message:

1. the name of the program that failed, `$0`
2. what it was trying to do, `open`
3. why it failed, `$!`

Without a newline at the end of the string passed to `die`, it appends the file and line number where your program died.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write UTF-8 data to a file (as you say in your XML declaration, open the file with a UTF-8 encoding:

```
open my($fh), '>:utf8', 'data.xml' or die "Could not open file: $!";

print $fh qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">\n};
```

Answer (score 0):

Several additional points of advice:

- For writing complex, structured
  files, use a library like
  [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Simple) or one of the [many,
  many others available on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml&mode=dist).
- If you are writing many very similar files, a templating module may be more appropriate.
- Take Ether's advice re: `open`, `strict` and `warnings`.  It will save you time debugging.
- If you are going to claim that a file has a particular encoding ([UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)), you probably should [emit actual Unicode text](http://blogs.msdn.com/brettsh/archive/2006/06/07/620986.aspx) to the file. There is more info in [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).