# Why doesn't 'opendir' have the same policy as 'open' in Perl Best Practices?

Tags: perl, perl-critic

Is there a reason why `opendir` doesn't have the same policy than `open` in [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735)?

I'm thinking about at least these 2 policies:

- [Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles)
- [Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::RequireBriefOpen](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::RequireBriefOpen)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip on the perl (5.6+) tools.  I had never seen the Critic package before, nor the non-bareword file handles.

Comment: @Roboprog: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-critic

Comment: @Roboprog: anyone still using 5.005 or earlier (and I know there are still quite a few) should at this point just be assuming new things they hear about won't work for them.  5.6 is just 11 weeks short of its 10th birthday!

Comment: Link to top level docs for Critic:  http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.105/lib/Perl/Critic.pm (for those like me to whom it is new  --  I don't do as much Perl as I used to)

Comment: That link will fail after a new version comes out. One that will always work is http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl::Critic

Comment: Unfortunately, back in 1999 we still had many hosts with perl 4 at my workplace at the time.  It's amazing how far (YEARS) behind a large company can have and keep things, and often for good-enough reasons  :-(

Comment: Cool, thanks for the "3 arg open" reference as well.  If I ever get back into doing a bunch of Perl again, I definitely need to scan the "best practices" list, and determine what the "least common denominator" is for the available installations.  My Blue Camel is more than a little aged, it seems, as a standard....  And finally,  does this mean I shouldn't use "local" any more, either?  :-)

Comment: @Roboprog: since you're asking, probably not, although `local` does have its uses. Search around here and you'll find a good discussion, or open up a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original rule from Perl Best Practices (for the first Policy you mention) was

> Don't use bareword filehandles

which applies to much more than just `open`.  Perl::Critic is based in large part on PBP but it does differ (from the perldoc):

> Perl::Critic is an extensible framework for creating and applying coding standards to Perl source code. Essentially, it is a static source code analysis engine. Perl::Critic is distributed with a number of Perl::Critic::Policy modules that attempt to enforce various coding guidelines. Most Policy modules are based on Damian Conway's book Perl Best Practices. **However, Perl::Critic is not limited to PBP and will even support Policies that contradict Conway.**

So the fact that Perl::Critic doesn't enforce the same rule on opendir is probably mostly an oversight.  It could also be blamed on the fact that the examples in PBP only use `open`.  I would suggest submitting a bug on CPAN (looking at the code, it would only be a one line change).

The second rule doesn't actually come from PBP but it seems to me it is just as applicable to opendir.  Again, a bug report to the author on CPAN would be a good idea since it would again only be a one line change.  And you might get more specific feedback if in fact it was an intentional decision.

**Correction:** it's a little different but the closest rule in PBP for the second Policy is

> Close filehandles explicitly, and as soon as possible.

and fixing that policy would be more than a one liner but still relatively easy if the maintainer thought it warranted (and wasn't worried that it would break too much existing code).

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:  files are used much more often, and nobody got around to doing the "lint-ish" work on directory handles yet.

FYI:  if you really wanted to enforce these, you could implement something to emulate the Ruby open + block metaphor:  Make an open/close wrapper sub which takes another sub as a parameter to do the actual I/O between the open and close.  I could put a code sample in, but I'm kind of wandering off topic.

Answer (score 0):

ask the author? I know it seems kind of smart-arsed answer, but going to the source is the easiest way to learn why