# How can I use Perl to get a SHA1 hash of a file from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, sha1

I have a file called *secure.txt* in *c:\temp*.  I want to run a Perl command from the command line to print the SHA1 hash of *secure.txt*.  I'm using ActivePerl 5.8.2.  I have not used Perl before, but it's the most convenient option available right now.

Comment: Hello from the future! Both ActiveState and Strawberry Perl include Digest::SHA's [`shasum` command](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Digest-SHA/shasum), and it should already be your `%PATH%` if you chose the default options during install. If you really, _really_ want to write your own wrapper for Digest::SHA, then the other answers here are terrific. But if you would rather use a command-line tool that just _happens_ to be provided by a "standard" Perl module, see my answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
perl -MDigest::SHA1=sha1_hex -le "print sha1_hex <>" secure.txt
```

The command-line options to Perl are documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). Going from left to right in the above command:

- `-MDigest::SHA1=sha1_hex` loads the [Digest::SHA1](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egaas/Digest-SHA1-2.12/SHA1.pm) module at compile time and imports `sha1_hex`, which gives the digest in hexadecimal form.
- [`-l`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D) automatically adds a newline to the end of any [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/print.html)
- [`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-e*-_commandline_) introduces Perl code to be executed

The funny-looking diamond is a special case of Perl’s [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) operator:

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of `sed` and `awk`. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames.

Because `secure.txt` is the only file named on the command line, its contents become the argument to `sha1_hex`.

With Perl version 5.10 or later, you can shorten the above one-liner by five characters.

```
perl -MDigest::SHA=sha1_hex -E 'say sha1_hex<>' secure.txt
```

The code drops the optional (with all versions of Perl) whitespace before [`<>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html), drops [`-l`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D), and switches from [`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-e*-_commandline_) to [`-E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-E*-_commandline_).

> - **`-E commandline`**
>
>   behaves just like [`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-e*-_commandline_), except that it implicitly enables all optional features (in the main compilation unit). See [`feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

One of those optional features is [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/say.html), which makes [`-l`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D) unnecessary.

> - **`say FILEHANDLE LIST`**
> - **`say LIST`**
> - **`say`**
>
>   Just like [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/functions/print.html), but implicitly appends a newline. `say LIST` is simply an abbreviation for
>
>   ```
>     { local $\ = "\n"; print LIST }
>   ```
>
>   This keyword is only available when the `say` feature is enabled: see [`feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

If you’d like to have this code in a convenient utility, say `mysha1sum.pl`, then use

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Digest::SHA;

die "Usage: $0 file ..\n" unless @ARGV;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
  my $sha1 = Digest::SHA->new(1);  # use 1 for SHA1, 256 for SHA256, ...
  $sha1->addfile($file);
  say($sha1->hexdigest, "  $file");
}
```

This will compute a digest for each file named on the command line, and the output format is compatible with that of the Unix `sha1sum` utility.

```
C:\> mysha1sum.pl mysha1sum.pl mysha1sum.pl 
8f3a7288f1697b172820ef6be0a296560bc13bae  mysha1sum.pl
8f3a7288f1697b172820ef6be0a296560bc13bae  mysha1sum.pl
```

You didn’t say whether you have Cygwin installed, but if you do, `sha1sum` is part of the coreutils package.

Comment: nit: because secure.txt is the only file, its contents become the argument*S* to sha1_hex (each line a separate argument).  As it happens, sha1_hex joins its arguments back together and gives the SHA1 of the whole file, but use of <> other places won't necessarily work that way.

Answer (score 7):

Try the [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.48/lib/Digest/SHA.pm) module.

```
C:\> perl -MDigest::SHA -e "print Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile('secure.txt')->hexdigest"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, both [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and [ActiveState Perl](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/) include the [`shasum`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Digest-SHA/shasum) command that comes with [Digest::SHA](https://metacpan.org/release/Digest-SHA). If you chose the default options during setup, this will already be in your `%PATH%`.

If you really, really **want** to write your own wrapper for Digest::SHA, the other answers here are great.

If you just want to "use Perl" to get the SHA1 hash for a file, in the sense that you *have* ActiveState Perl, and it comes with the `shasum` command-line utility, it's as simple as:

```
shasum secure.txt
```

The default hashing algorithm is SHA1; add `-a1` if you want to be explicit (not a bad idea).

The default output format is the hash, two spaces, then the filename. This is the same format as [`sha1sum`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sha1sum) and similar utilities, commonly found on Unix/Linux systems. If redirected into a file, that filename can be given to `shasum -c` later in order to verify the integrity whatever files you had hashed previously.

If you really, *really* don't want to see the filename, just the SHA1 hash, either of these will chop off the filename part:

Using Powershell:

```bsh
shasum secure.txt | %{$_split()[0]}
```

Using Command Prompt (old-school batch scripting):

```
for /f %i in ('shasum secure.txt') do echo %i
```

For the second one, make sure you use `%%i` instead of `%i` (both places) if you're putting that in a `.cmd` or `.bat` file.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Digest::SHA1`](https://metacpan.org/release/GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.12/view/SHA1.pm) like so:

Using the OO strategy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use v5.10; # for 'say'
use strict;

require Digest::SHA1;
my $filename = 'secure.txt';
my $sha1 = Digest::SHA1->new->addfile($filename)->hexdigest;
say $sha1;
```

*Note that calling `->hexdigest` causes the object's state to clear, causing the current digest it's calculating to be destroyed. You can re-use the `$sha1` object at that point.*

You can also use `sha1_hex` sub on the file contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Digest::SHA1 qw/ sha1_hex /;

my $filename = "secure.txt";
# open file
open my $fhi, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open file '$filename' for reading: $!";
# slurp all the file contents
my $file_contents;
{local $/; $file_contents = <$fhi>;}
close $fhi;
print &sha1_hex($file_contents);
```

Note that you can use [`Digest::SHA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA) instead, where `new()` takes the algorithm to use as parameter (e.g. 1 for SHA1, 256 for SHA256, ...):

```
require Digest::SHA;
my $sha1 = Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile($filename)->hexdigest();
```

Comment: Please use local lexical filehandles - `open my $in_data, '<', 'secure.txt' or die ...`

Comment: There are good reasons to use lexical handles.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Comment: Use good habits even when you don't need to so they stay habits when you do need to. :)

Comment: There is a way to do it with out reading the contents of the file yourself.