# How do I open a file whose full name is unknown with Perl?

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

I want to know if there is anything that lets me do the following:

```
folder1 has files "readfile1" "f2" "fi5"
```

The only thing I know is that I need to read the file which starts with `readfile`, and I don't know what's there in the name after the string `readfile`. Also, I know that no other file in the directory starts with `readfile`.

How do I open this file with the `open` command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) can be used to find a file matching a certain string:

```
my ($file) = glob 'readfile*';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can not open $file: $!";
```

Comment: Upvoted because of the simple solution and because of correct error handling.

Comment: Well, to be complete, you should check for glob errors as well and if the return is null

Comment: Yea, he did the error handling right -- but will the OP? Advocating `autodie` is more honorable.

Comment: When assigning the first of a list, I prefer to do:  `my $file = ( glob 'readfile*' )[0];` just to make the extraction from the list more explicit so some idiot doesn't come along and make my list assignment a scalar assignment and break things.

Comment: @Evan Carrol: Not fully. `glob 'readfile*` could return empty list, multiple files, or a directory. So, to be complete, these would need to be checked, no? Agreed on `autodie` though...

Comment: so long as the open () call fails, `autodie` will catch it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glob` for simple cases, as toolic suggests.

```
my ($file) = glob 'readfile*';
```

If the criteria for finding the correct file are more complex, just read the entire directory and use the **full power of Perl** to winnow the list down to what you need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);

my $dir   = shift @ARGV;
my @files = read_dir($dir);

# Filter the list as needed.
@files = map { ... } @files;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need imports to read the contents of the directory - perl has some built-in functions that can do that:

```
opendir DIR, ".";
my ($file) = grep /readfile.*/, readdir(DIR);

open FILE, $file or die $!;
```

Comment: Correct, but it is better to use lexical file handles and a 3 argument open.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice