# Can clear case perl - ccperl handle with a path contains spaces?

Tags: perl, clearcase

I'm trying to open a file with path contains space, say:

```
open(FILE, "some\\path with spaces")
```

I'm working with `ccperl` on Windows, and I get an error *"can't open file"*.

I've already tried `q!"..."!` tried `"\path\ with\ spaces"` and many more...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. On my ActivePerl 5.14.2 I can do the following, which works:

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict; use warnings;
open my $fh, '<', 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\Desktop\file spaces.txt'
  or die $!;
print while <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

The difference to what you've done is that I used single quotes `'`. Inside them, the backslash `\` is not seen as a meta character, so there's no need to escape it. You also do not need to escape the spaces. You should try that out.

---

On a side note, are you using `strict` and `warnings`? They might tell you what is wrong, as well as my `or die $!` might.

I'd also suggest you use the [three argument form](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) of `open` and [lexical filehandles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3276699/1331451).

Answer (score 1):

From [this matrix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245227), ccperl usually means perl 5.8.6 with ClearCase.

The [ccperl scripts examples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html) suggests: `"\"your file path\""`, but that might not be compatible with `open`.