# Are filehandles in perl global?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
sub trial
{
    open (LOGFILE, 'C:\Users\out.txt');
    trial();
}
trial();
```

*Please ignore that it will go into an infinite loop.*

Will the filehandle `LOGFILE` be local or private to the method?
If no, how can I make it private/local?
I'm aware of **my** . But I don't know how to use it on File Handles.

Comment: These are filehandles, not file handlers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those filehandles are global because they are [typeglobs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles). This can lead to very bad surprises sometimes, because you might by accident overwrite such a filehandle that was defined inside of some module you are using.

If you want lexical filehandles, define them with `my` like this:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'C:\Users\out.txt';
```

See also:

- [Which one is good practice, a lexical filehandle or a typeglob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276674/which-one-is-good-practice-a-lexical-filehandle-or-a-typeglob)
- [brian d foy on 'Why we teach bareword filehandles' in *Learning Perl*](http://www.learning-perl.com/?p=235)

Answer (score 4):

Lexical file handles are just standard `my` scalars. See the examples in [the perldoc for `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
open (my $logfile, 'C:\Users\out.txt');
```

In general, the three argument form of `open` is preferred too:

```
open (my $logfile, '<', 'C:\Users\out.txt');
```