# perl script added database insert statement stop after some time while in a loop

Tags: database, perl, connection

I've converted **script1** to **script2** to have db insert statements. However my script2 stops after some time like I run out of memory after putting scripts in a loop. If I only run script1 then loop run forever. What am I missing?

### script1

```
logupdate("${cid}_$mon$day${year}_${time}_${status}.csv",
       "$uid|$ext||$cid|$did|$status\n");

# log to file
sub logupdate
{
       my $log = shift;
       unless (open(LOG, ">>$path$log"))
       {
               print STDERR "Can't write to $path$log: $!\n";
       }
       print LOG @_;
       close LOG;
}
```

### script2

```
{
       my $filedata = "${cid}";                           
       my $filename = "$status";                      
       logupdate("${cid}",  "$status");
}

# log to file
sub logupdate
{
    my $filedata = shift;
    my $filename = shift;

    if ( not $dbh ) {
        $dbh = DBI->connect( $url, $user, $dbpass );
        sleep 6;
    print "reconnecting to db.... Success!\n";
    }
    if ( not $filedata eq '') {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO cliinfo (calltype, callno) 
             VALUES(?,      ?)');
    $sth->execute($filename, $filedata);
    print "Inserting into db $filename:\t\t$filedata\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing ... `use strict;`, `use warnings;`, `open` with lexical filehandles. At least you are not missing SQL placeholders.

Comment: @rana, here is a question relating to mob's comment about lexical filehandles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276674/which-one-is-good-practice-a-lexical-filehandle-or-a-typeglob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using $dbh as global variable then initialize $dbh with 'my';

```
my $dbh;
```

Disconnect DB connection within the function;

```
$dbh->disconnect();
```

To be even safer, at the end of function assign undef to $dbh variable;

```
$dbh = undef;
```