# perl - sort by MAC Address

Tags: perl, sorting, mac-address

I have a long .csv file that consists of device information.  Each line is a unique device with its own info listed as such:

```
MACaddr,,,,Date,Date,,"b,n",,blahblahblah
```

What I need to do is take in the file and then write to a new file with all lines/devices that have the same Vendor MAC (i.e. the first 3 octets of the MAC Address) grouped together.  I can easily take in each line and grab the Vendor MAC with a regex but then I am stuck.

All I have is:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open IN, "wirelessClients.csv" or die "Couldn't open file\n$!";
open OUT, ">sortedClients.csv" or die "Couldn't open out file\n$!";

my @clients = <IN>;

foreach my $client (@clients)
{
    if($client =~ /^(\w+:\w+:\w+)/)
    {
        print OUT "$1,$client\n\n"; 
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to go about sorting the information.

Any help and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider [using lexical filehandles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3276771/132382) unless you've a deep reason not to.

Comment: Oh wow, well that was incredibly simple... I was thinking wayyyyyy to hard. Thank you!

Comment: And good information, pilcrow, thank you.  I will adjust my ways.

Comment: You're welcome. Moved to an answer so you can close off the question.

Comment: @pilcrow On an 8-line script?!  Whyever for? That’s like saying never have mainline code, but only write modules with subroutines. There are plenty of more important things to worry about.\n\n\n\n

Comment: No, @tchrist, it's more like saying please consider using lexical filehandles by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the MAC address is the first element, a simple sort should group ones with the same first 3 octets:

```
sort wirelessClients.csv > sortedClients.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

As we're looking at the first octets anyway you can simply sort <strike>numerically</strike> alphanumerically:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


open (my $in, '<', "wirelessClients.csv") or die "Cannot open Infile: $!";
open (my $out, '>',"sortedClients.csv") or die "Cannot open Outfile: $!";

my @clients = <$in>;

my @sorted = sort {$a cmp $b} @clients;

foreach @sorted {
    print $out $_;
}
```

Comment: You want stringwise `cmp`, not `<=>`, as these are MACs in "hex-colon" canonical format, and the OP needs to group by the first three octets.  Also, the comma after `$out` won't do what you want.