# Single perl script used by parallelly by different threads at the same time stamp

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-management, file-io

I am using a file i/o based perl script. This script will be used in parallel by many threads. There is a chance of two threads use it at the same time stamp. I am using file i/o in the script i.e

```
open(FILE,"<",$file_array);
my @file_array = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
```

1) Is there a chance of resource sharing conflict on @file_array data structure between two parallel threads using the script at the same time stamp.

2) If so how to avoid it?

3) How does the memory allocation is handled during such cases?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Without more code, you are safe.  You have copied the content of the file without modifying it, therefore there is no issue.  Reading a file should never cause a conflict...

Comment: Check out these two questions to learn why lexical file handles, such as `my $fh` are better than using typeglobs, such as `FILE` when opening files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276674/which-one-is-good-practice-a-lexical-filehandle-or-a-typeglob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-autovivified-filehandles-a-perl-best-pract

Answer (score 2):

@file_array gets a unique memory address per process.  Nothing to worry about.