# How can I find the last line that ends with "PASS" in my text file?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
--------- Voltage = 1.150000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.140000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.130000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.120000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.110000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.100000 V --------->PASS




--------- Voltage = 1.090000 V --------->FAIL
```

I want to retrieve the last passing value, which in this case is `1.100000V`. How can I do this with a regular expression? I tried the following but it does not give the correct answer:

```
open(my $FH, $FileName) or die "$!\n";

while($line = <$FH>)
{
    if($line =~ /FAIL/)
    {
        if($line =~ m/^\d*\.?\d*/) #check for the decimal number? not sure
        {
            print $&;   # I intend to print the matched number here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The delimiter I use is "\n\n\n\n".
Defined as $/ = "\n\n\n\n";

Comment: Thank you all for your help.I will follow up this problem along.
Update you with my final solution or further questions.
Perl has such an active community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a number at the start of the string because of the `^`. Of course, there isn't one there. You could extract the number with `/(\d+(?:\.\d+))/`, but why not just take what follows `Voltage =`?

You say you want the last passing voltage, but you try to capture the failing voltage!

Avoid `$&` as it slows down every match and substitution without captures.

```
open(my $FH, $FileName)
   or die "$!\n";

my $passing_voltage;
while ($line = <$FH>) {
   if (my ($voltage) = $line =~ /Voltage = (\S+)/) {
      last if $line =~ /FAIL/;
      $passing_voltage = $voltage;
   }
}

die("No passing voltage\n") if !defined($passing_voltage);
print("$passing_voltage\n");
```

No need to touch `$/`.

---

The above is quite simple, but it can be simplified a bit further by reading the file from end to front.

```
use File::ReadBackwards qw( );

my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new($FileName)
   or die("$!\n");

my $voltage;
while ( defined( my $line = $fh->readline() ) ) {
   if ($line =~ /Voltage = (\S+).*PASS/) {
      $voltage = $1;
      last;
   }
}

die("No passing voltage\n") if !defined($voltage);
print("$voltage\n");
```

Comment: This captures the value of the fail but where is the last good pass value?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Regarding to the last good pass value.
When all passes, then last pass should be the expected value.
When it fails at any point, then last good pass value is the expected value.
THIS QUESTION IS STILL OPEN.

Answer (score 1):

This reads the entire file, then prints the number from the last line which matched.

```
while (<>)
{
    # last if m/FAIL$/;  # see below
    next unless m/(\d+\.\d) V/;  # Capture number in $1
    $keep = $1 if m/PASS$/;
}
print $keep;
```

For optimization, if you know that the first `FAIL` will not be followed by any `PASS`es, uncomment the `last` line.

As a one-liner,

```
perl -ne 'next unless m/(\d+\.\d+) V .*PASS$/; $k = $1; END { print $k }' filename
```

Comment: The input is a file not keyboard.

Comment: @alexmac The file name needs to be passed as a command line argument when invoking the script.

Comment: +1 Personally, I like your one-liner! Though it (and your fuller answer) will fail if somebody has their probes on back-to-front and the voltage comes out negative :-)

Comment: did they say pass it in as a command line? its part of a large set of code I imagine. I am not mean enough to down vote it though.

Comment: @alexmac Feel free to put an `open` at the beginning of the script if Unix tool design is alien to you.  Better yet, learn to appreciate the flexibility.

Comment: @tripleee, agreed a person has to be flexible I still hold to my statement that its' outside the params asked for in the question.  Though, I do like your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Hmmmm .

```
open(my $FH, $FileName) or die "$!\n";
# suggested change for poster is 
# open (FH, $fileName) } or die "found not open file $1\n";
$lastPass = "init"; # in the event of a fail on first line.

while($line = <FH>){
   next if $line =~ /^$/;  # if no string data why even bother
   if($line =~ /FAIL/i){   # look for a fail 
      print "fail detected  $line \n";  #print a warning
      last;        # exit the loop
   }
   else {
    if ($line =~ m/(\d*\.?\d*)/) {  # if the line is not a fail record
       $lastPass = $line;
       $voltage = $1;  # voltage if you want it in the $1 regex memory
    }       
  }

}
# close (FH);  # suggestion
if ($lastPass eq "init") {   # did we find a fail before a pass.
  print "detected fail before good data \n";
}
else {
  print $lastPass, "\n";
  print $voltage , "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great, that's elegant.
One tiny problem, if you defined $pass but never modify the value in between, then the if ($pass eq "init") will always gets printed out.

Comment: It's functional, sure, but not elegant. There's cruft that can be removed to make it [elegant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22384342/589924)

Comment: Doesn't compile with `use strict;`.

Comment: ... and writes errors to STDOUT, outputs spaces before newlines, etc

Comment: yeah,sure. I commented out the use strict pragma. But the condition 
if($pass eq "init") is always true. Any comment?

Comment: @user3368737 Don't comment out `use strict;` just to get some code working that you found on the internet. You should *always* use it. If something doesn't work with `strict`, there's a problem with the *code*, not with `strict`.

Comment: Silly me, $pass change to $lastPass

Comment: I am writing an example, I don;'t want to keep typing my etc for the guy, works fine if *i* actually paid attention to variable names :) @user3368736 I corrected the pass eq item, it was programmer error on my part.

Comment: That's a fantastic job indeed.

Comment: @user3368737, sorry and forgive me for the stupid $pass eq issue, the others are correct about strict and you can also do a -w on your perl line '#!/usr/bin/perl -w'  its 2pm and i need more coffee :)

Comment: Even after your edit, doesn't work with `strict`. Your suggestion to use typeglobs (`FH`) instead of lexical filehandles (`my $fh`) is [just bad advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3276771/176646).