# how do I list contents of local directory on ftp?

Tags: perl, ftp

I am trying to send files to a remote host via a Perl script. To do this I want list the local directory then choose files to upload as I iterate through the files list using the following commands:

```
my @files = '!ls'; does not work
my @files = 'lls'; does not work either
```

Then I want to do:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
next if -d $file;
next unless $file =~ /^gateway_data/;
$ftp->put($file) or warn "Failed '$file': $! ($^E)";
}
```

Is there another command, apart from the two above, to make the list of files in the local directory?
Assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
opendir(my $DIR, './') or die $!;
my @files = readdir($DIR);
foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if -d $file;
    next unless $file =~ /^gateway_data/;
    $ftp->put($file) or warn "Failed '$file': $! ($^E)";
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks very much @ProfGhost, though am yet to try it I think this should definitely work.

Comment: @mpapec could you explain me why you changed the filehandle to a variable?

Comment: Typeglobs are more error prone than lexical variables; http://stackoverflow.com/a/3276771/223226 So due global nature, it should be localized first ie. `local *DIR;` which adds more noise to the code, and less understanding to non seasoned perl programmers.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution has worked fine for me. Thanks so much.