# Extracting the first two characters from a file in perl into another file

Tags: bash, perl

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my code below -- I'm trying to figure out how to open up all these text files (.csv files that end in DIS that **all have one line in them**) and get the first two characters (these are all numbers) from them and print them into another file of the same name, with a ".number" suffix. Some of these .DIS files don't have anything in them, in which case I want to print "0".

Lastly, I would like to go through each original .DIS file and delete the first 3 characters -- I did this through bash.

```
my @DIS = <*.DIS>; 
foreach my $file (@DIS){
    my $name = $file;
    my $output = "$name.number";
    open(INHANDLE, "< $file") || die("Could not open file"); 
    while(<INHANDLE>){
        open(OUT_FILE,">$output") || die; 
        my $line = $_;
        chomp ($line);
        my $string = $line;
        if ($string eq ""){  
        print "0";      
        } else {
        print substr($string,0,2);
        }   
    }
    system("sed -i 's/\(.\{3\}\)//' $file");  
}
```

When I run this code, I get a list of numbers are concatenated together and empty .DIS.number files. I'm rather new to Perl, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do it like this

Each `*.dis` file is opened and the contents read into `$text`. Then a regex substitution is used to remove the first three characters from the string and capture the first two in `$1`

If the substitution succeeded then the contents of `$1` are written to the number file, otherwise the original file is empty (or shorter than two characters) and a zero is written instead. The remaining contents of `$text` are then written back to the `*.dis` file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

for my $dis_file ( glob '*.DIS' ) {

    my $text = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $dis_file;
        <$fh>;
    };

    my $num_file = "$dis_file.number";

    open my $dis_fh, '>', $dis_file;
    open my $num_fh, '>', $num_file;

    if ( defined $text and $text =~ s/^(..).?// ) {
        print $num_fh "$1\n";
        print $dis_fh $text;
    }
    else {
        print $num_fh "0\n";
        print $dis_fh "-\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- all files are now showing up, but I am getting a few errors. num_files where the original dis_file had nothing do not have "0" in them. Many of these files just have the same number as another num_file where the original dis_file was nonzero. I receive the error of "Use of uninitialized value $text in print at line 20" and "Use of uninitialized value $text in substitution (s///) at line 13." I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Is this because some of the dis_files are not defined? Lastly, is there a way to print a "-" in the original DIS files if they are empty? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: Sorry, I made a silly mistake. It should work better now

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. It does work better now, but I'm still getting an error of "use of uninitialized value $text in substitution (s///) at line 13." Also, I changed `print $fh "-\n";` to `print $fh "0";` -- I was wondering if if I could print "-" in original DIS file, not the new num_file.

Comment: @Justin: If the substitution is on your line 13 then you've omitted two lines from my script; I hope they're just blank lines! And I'm sorry I'm not thinking straight today; try the new version

Comment: Thanks so much -- it all works correctly now! Just had one question -- I understand that `s/^(..).?//` is a substitution, but I was wondering if you could explain to me exactly what is happening there. I would like to keep note of it as I move forward learning perl!

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this code, I get a list of numbers are concatenated together and empty .DIS.number files.

This is because of this line.

```
print substr($string,0,2);
```

`print` defaults to printing to STDOUT (ie. the screen).  You need to give it the filehandle to print to.

```
print OUT_FILE substr($string,0,2);
```

They're being concatenated because `print` just prints what you tell it to, it won't put newlines in for you (there are some [global variables which can change this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), don't mess with them).  You have to add the newline yourself.

```
print OUT_FILE substr($string,0,2), "\n";
```

---

As a final note, when working with files in Perl I would suggest using [lexical filehandles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276674/which-one-is-good-practice-a-lexical-filehandle-or-a-typeglob), [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), and [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html).  They will avoid a great number of classic problems working with files in Perl.

Comment: Thank you so much -- I'll keep this in mind when using print in the future!

Comment: One last question -- now the DIS.number files are getting created, but only when the DIS file >0 KB (has something in it). The following code does not seem to output any DIS.number file with "0" in it : `if ($string eq ""){  
        print OUT_FILE "0";      
        }` 

Any idea why this may be? Is this because there isn't even a line for perl to compare the empty string to?

Comment: @Justin I suspect that if condition is not being triggered. `$string` may not be completely empty; it may contain whitespace such as spaces and newlines.  You're better off checking for `$string !~ /\S/` which checks to see if the string doesn't contain non-whitespace characters.  That's a double negative and hard to understand, so flip your condition around: `if( $string =~ /\S/ ) { print the first two characters } else { print 0 }`

Comment: I tried the fix but still have no luck. 

In essence, I have a bunch of files in the following format: file-55_357-#.csv.DIS, where # represents all even numbers 0 to 604 (303 files in total). Do you know of a quick workaround perl script or perhaps bash script that would scan to see if, for instance, file-55_357-80.csv.DIS existed and file-55_357-80.csv.DIS.number did not, I would print out another file with "0" in a file titled file-55_357-80.csv.DIS.number. 

I'm not sure how to start and isolate the number.

Answer (score -1):

this awk script extract the first two chars of each file to it's own file.  Empty files expected to have one empty line based on the spec.

```
awk 'FNR==1{pre=substr($0,1,2);pre=length(pre)==2?pre:0; print pre > FILENAME".number"}' *.DIS
```

This will remove the first 3 chars

```
cut -c 4-
```

Bash for loop will be better to do both, which we'll need to modify the awk script little bit

```
for f in *.DIS; 
do awk 'NR==1{pre=substr($0,1,2);$0=length(pre)==2?pre:0; print}' $f > $f.number; 
cut -c 4- $f > $f.cut; 
done
```

explanation:  loop through all files in *.DTS, for the first line of each file, try to get first two chars (1,2) of the line ($0) assign to pre.  If the length of pre is not two (either the line is empty or with 1 char only) set the line to 0 or else use pre; print the line, output file name will be input file appended with .number suffix.  The $0 assignment is a trick to save couple keystrokes since print without arguments prints $0, otherwise you can provide the argument.

Ideally you should quote "$f" since it may contain space in file name...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- where would I exactly provide the argument, if I wanted to print "0" when the length(pre) !=2? Sorry about this, I'm just really new to bash and unused to the syntax.

Comment: ternary operator assigns zero if length is not equal to two.  `a=p?b:c` is equivalent to `if(p) a=b else a=c`.  You can rewrite the last part as `if(length(pre)==2) print pre else print 0`