# Search a compressed log file against a list of keywords

Tags: perl, grep

I am trying to open a log file, search it against a list of keywords, print every line that contained that keyword, and then compress the results file into a .gz.

I have come up with the code below, which starts running with no compilation errors. It writes to the results file, but when I run the script it never completes and it never finds any results. Any help?

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 

use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError) ;
use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %LOGLINES = ();
my %count = ();

open(FILE, "</data/bro/scripts/Keywords.txt"); 
my %keywords = map { chomp $_; $_, 1 } <FILE>; 
close(FILE);

my $logfile = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( "/data/bro/logs/2016-05-05/http.00:00:00-06:00:00.log.gz" )
    or die "IO::Uncompress::Gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n"; 

open(FILE, "+>Results.txt"); 
my @results = <FILE>; 

foreach my $line ($logfile) { 
    while (<>) {
        my @F=split("\t");
            next unless ($F[2] =~ /^(199|168|151|162|166|150)/);

        $count{ $F[2] }++;

        if ($count{ $F[2] } == 10) {
            print @{ $LOGLINES{$F[2]} };   # print all the log lines we've seen so far
            print $_;                      # print the current line
        } elsif ($count{ $F[2] } > 10) {
            print $_;                      # print the current line
        } else {
            push @{ $LOGLINES{$F[2]} }, $_; # store the log line for later use
        }

    my $flag_found = grep {exists $keywords{$_} } split /\s+/, $line;
    print $line if $flag_found;
    }
}
IO::Compress::Gzip("results.gz")
            or die "IO::Compress::Gunzip failed: $GzipError\n";   
close(FILE);
```

Comment: Generally the `while (<>)` line involves keyboard input. Perhaps this is why your script "never completes".

Comment: @red0ct is correct. What is the intention of the `while` loop? It wants you to input stuff. You're already looping the lines of `$logfile` with the `foreach` (although only once, because you don't call anything on the ::Gunzip object).

Comment: The while loop was to keep it searching each line of the log file until it reaches the end. Did I go about that the wrong way?

Comment: I think `while (<$logfile>)` will help you. Because AFAIK the object, returned by `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new` can be handled like normal filehandle..

Comment: Also, why do you open Results.txt in read-write mode? You never use `@results`, and you don't write to `FILE` either. You have `strict` and `warnings`, and your code looks pretty good. Also use three-argument-open to make it even better. :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably there is no need in `while (<>)` loop in your script, because this line involves the input from keyboard.

The object `$logfile` returned by `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new` [constructor](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html#Constructor) can be handled like normal filehandle, so you could just do `while (<$logfile>)` like:

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError) ;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

#...
my @loglines;

open my $fh, '</data/bro/scripts/Keywords.txt' or die "$!";
my %keywords = map { chomp; $_ => 0 } <$fh>;
close $fh;

my $logfile = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( "..." )
    or die "IO::Uncompress::Gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n"; 

while (<$logfile>) {
    my @line = split /\t/;
    next if ! $line[2];
    for my $key (keys %keywords) {
        if ($line[2] =~ /^$key/) { $keywords{$key}++; push @loglines, $_; say; last  }
    }
}
# ... pack using gzip
```

So the `@loglines` array contains all lines from log, which contains one of your keywords at the beggining of third (`$line[2]`) splitted by '\t' substring. The `%keywords` hash contains keywords as keys and their frequencies of occurrence as values.

---

**NOTES**(Edit): You can store loglines in hash, where each key could be a keyword and each value - an array/hash of matched lines (or substrings or both). I simply push matched lines into array just for example. You can do it as you need and then pack it with gzip in convenient way.
Also it's better not to use the global names like `FILE` because in such case there is a risk to have other code using it by accident. Besides verify that you've successfully opened filehandle e.g. with `or die` as in example.

Comment: @MichaelMeis Edited.
Also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276674/which-one-is-good-practice-a-lexical-filehandle-or-a-typeglob)

Answer (score 1):

IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new returns an IO::Uncompress::Gunzip object.

```
foreach my $line ($logfile) { 
    while (<>) {
      ...
    }
}
```

makes no sense, it just sets $line to the IO::Uncompress::Gunzip object and then waits for keyboard input.

Instead try:

```
while (my $line = <$logfile>) {
  ...
}
```

You are also not using IO::Compress::Gzip correctly. You can create the IO::Compress::Gzip object before you process the logfile and use it with the print. Something like the following should work:

```
...
my $z = IO::Compress::Gzip->new("results.gz")
            or die "IO::Compress::Gunzip failed: $GzipError\n";
while (my $line = <$logfile>) {
    my @F=split("\t", $line);
        next unless ($F[2] =~ /^(199|168|151|162|166|150)/);

    $count{ $F[2] }++;

    if ($count{ $F[2] } == 10) {
        print $z @{ $LOGLINES{$F[2]} };   # print all the log lines we've seen so far
        print $z $line;                      # print the current line
    } elsif ($count{ $F[2] } > 10) {
        print $z $line;                      # print the current line
    } else {
        push @{ $LOGLINES{$F[2]} }, $_; # store the log line for later use
    }

    my $flag_found = grep {exists $keywords{$_} } split /\s+/, $line;
    print $z $line if $flag_found;
}
```

You should look at the documentation for IO::Uncompress::Gunzip and IO::Compress::Gzip (using perldoc or at cpan.org). It shows examples of the correct usage of these modules.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still royally confused but I think this has me headed in the correct direction now. I'm reading more up on gzip and researching the new errors I'm having.