# How can I scan a filehandle twice to copy it based on its contents?

Tags: regex, perl

My overall perl script is trying to operate as follows:

- Read source file for content
- Find regex match and use that match for Destination filename
- Open new Destination filename
- Find regex match for C format comments /* */ that contain a keyword, i.e. abcd
- Write string matches found to destination filename

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $src = 'D:\\Scripts\\sample.c';
my $fileName;

# open source file for reading
open(SRC,'<',$src) or die $!;

while(my $row = <SRC>){
    if ($row =~ /([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\.[a-z,0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\.[a-z,0-9]{3})/){
        $fileName = $1;
    }
}

my $des = "D:\\Scripts\\" . $fileName . ".txt";

# open destination file for writing
open(DES,'>',$des) or die $!;

print("copying content from $src to $des\n");

while(my $row = <SRC>){
    if ($row =~ /(\/\*.*abcd.[\s\S]*?\*\/)/){
        print DES $1;
    }
}

# always close the filehandles
close(SRC);

close(DES);
print "File content copied successfully!\n";
```

I am running this in Windows 10 command line with Perl 5.32.1. My problem is I am not getting any content writing to the destination file. The file gets created but no content gets written to it. When I change:

```
print DES $1; -> print "$1\n";
```

I get no content coming out the command line window either. When I move the entire second if statement to be nested underneath the first while loop after the 1st if statement I get output to the command line. But I cannot keep the 2nd if statement there because I want it to write to the destination file.

Comment: Do those C comments always fit on a single line?

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited my post to make the question and situation more clear.

Comment: seek! Oh man I was stumped, thank you!

Comment: yeah :)  Or you can close and re-open.  With a lexical filehandle once you leave the scope in which that `open` was issued -- say, in a function -- the file gets closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `$src` file is read the first time the `SRC` filehandle reaches the file end. So when you try to read the file again, there is nothing to read on that filehandle (and it won't tell).

After the first read is done reposition the filehandle to the beginning of the file

```
seek SRC, 0, 0;
```

There are nice symbolic constants that can be used with [seek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek), see [Fcntl](https://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl)

Another option is to close and open the file again. (Or even just re-open the same filehandle to it, in which case it gets closed first.)

---

Note: it is just better to use lexical filehandles than typeglobs, like

```
open my $src_fh, '<', $src_file  or die $!;
```

See a comment on it [in perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), and search SO posts (here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276674/4653379) for example).

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the problem slightly. Instead of reading the file twice, read it once. Write to a temp file where the name is not important. Along the way, discover the final filename. After you are done, rename the temp file.