# Finding it hard to fix this.Please guide by checking my edited code

Tags: perl

I want to retrive the no of functions(only defined functions and not the calling functions) present in a in a text file(count)

The text file{function.txt}is below

```
#include<main.h>
#include<mncl.h>
int reg23;
int refid23;
int64 AccounntBalance(char *reg12,char *refid,char **id){  //dis is function1
ref();
if(id>100)
  {
  do(&ref);
  }
}                                                        //dis is end of fucntion1
void AccountRetrivalForm(char **regid,char **balance,char **id)   //dis is function2
   {
   doref(); 
   int register;
   if(refid!=null)
    {
   dolog();
     }
   }                                                     //dis is end of function2
```

Now the program as per my logic is:

```
 #!C:/strawberry/perl
 use strict; 
 use warnings; 
 my $filename = 'function_perl.txt';
 my $function_count = 0;
 open(FILENAME,$filename);
 my @arr = join("\n",<FILENAME>);
foreach  my $string(@arr)
  {
 if($string =~/(?:int64|void|boolean)\s?(.*?)\(.*?\)\s*\{/)
     {
 print "HAI";
 $function_count++;
 print '$function_count';
  }
  }
```

Here Function_count is 1.It never increment for the second match....Please help me with the same code...I am trying so long.I find it hard to fix this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Functions starting with (int64) or (void) or (boolean) ?

Comment: @gorillaPatch
I am try to match all functions that may start with int64 or void or boolean(These are the only three possiblites)

Comment: I'm curious, what language is "dis" from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is ill-formed.

```
^([int64/void/boolean)]/(.*)/\(/\{//\n
```

You probably *meant* something like:

```
/^(int64|void|boolean)\s+(\w+)\s*\(.*?\)\s*\{/
```

That is, one of `int64`, `void`, or `boolean`, some whitespace, an identifier, optional whitespace, an opening parenthesis, some content, a closing parenthesis, some optional whitespace (which might be a newline), and an opening curly brace.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this example will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n;

# Supply the input file name as a command-line argument.
# Perl will open the file and process it line by line.
# No need to hard-code the file name in the program, which
# means the script could be reused.
while (my $line = <>){
    # The regex is applied against $line.
    # It will return the items captured by parentheses.
    # The /x option causes Perl to ignore whitespace
    # in our definition of the regex -- for readability.
    my ($type, $func, $args) = $line =~ /^
        ( int64|void|boolean ) \s+
        ( \w+ )                \s*
        \( (.+?) \)
    /x;

    # Skip the line if our regex failed.
    next unless defined $type;

    # Keep track of N of functions, print output, whatever...
    $n ++;
    print $_, "\n" for '', $type, $func, $args;
}

print "\nN of functions = $n\n";
```

Comment: Nice one! I like it how you directly name the matches of the regexp. Makes the code so much more readable. I learned something today. Thanks! +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to say that the way you go through the file is unusual. Usually you would use something like

```
open my $handle, '<', $filename;
while (<$handle>) {
    if (/^(void|boolean|int64).../) {
        do something;
    }
}
close $handle;
```

What the code does is it opens the file and reads in one line at a time. This is the same as you do by getting the whole array, joining it and iterating over its elements.

An unrelated however important hint for using Perl: include the three lines after the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie qw(:all);
```

This warns you if there are some unassigned variables you try to use in a concatenation for example and other things. The strict package forces you to declare variables with the `my` keyword. This sounds like a bit of hassle but it also prevents you from getting problems because you just mistyped a variable. With using strict the Perl interpreter will warn you about an undeclared variable. The autodie pragma checks for failure on system calls such as `open`.

The regexp you are using is wrong. You have to be aware that regexps in Perl are enclosed by slashes, so `/\s+\w*.*/` is a valid regexp. You are using here a slash in your regexp which closes the expression prematurely. If you have to match agains slashes in your text you would have to escape them using a backslash or use a different delimiter altogether.

BTW, you also have a typo: `@filecontent` vs. `@file_content`. This is a perfect place where `use strict;` would have warned you.

Comment: @daxim Thanks for the edits. Why is it better to use a file handle of the form $handle instead of FILENAME ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Comment: Thanks for the tip that you provided daxim

Comment: @daxim Thanks alot. Herzlichen Dank!

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not parsers. It's always better to use a parser if you can.

A simple approach is to lean on the parser in [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub usage { "Usage: $0 source-file\n" }

die usage unless @ARGV == 1;

open my $ctags, "-|", "ctags", "-f", "-", @ARGV
  or die "$0: failed to start ctags\n";

while (<$ctags>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  next unless $fields[-1] eq "f";
  print $fields[0], "\n";
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./getfuncs prog.cc
AccounntBalance
AccountRetrivalForm
```

Another approach involves g++'s option [`-fdump-translation-unit`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#IDX275) that causes it to dump a representation of the parse tree, and you could dig through it as in the following example.

We begin with the usual front matter:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
```

Processing requires the name of the source file and any necessary compiler flags.

```
sub usage { "Usage: $0 source-file [ cflags ]\n" }
```

The translation-unit dump has a straightforward format:

```
@1      namespace_decl   name: @2       srcp: :0      
                         dcls: @3      
@2      identifier_node  strg: ::       lngt: 2       
@3      function_decl    name: @4       mngl: @5       type: @6      
                         srcp: prog.c:12               chan: @7      
                         args: @8       link: extern  
@4      identifier_node  strg: AccountRetrivalForm     lngt: 19
```

As you can see, each record begins with an identifier, followed by a type, and then one or more attributes. Regular expressions and a bit of hash twiddling are sufficient to give us a tree to inspect.

```
sub read_tu {
  my($path) = @_;
  my %node;

  open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
  my $tu = do { local $/; <$fh> };

  my $attrname = qr/\b\w+(?=:)/;
  my $attr =
    qr/($attrname): \s+ (.+?)      # name-value
       (?= \s+ $attrname | \s*$ )  # terminated by whitespace or EOL
      /xm;

  my $fullnode =
    qr/^(@\d+) \s+ (\S+) \s+  # id and type
        ((?: $attr \s*)+)     # one or more attributes
        \s*$                  # consume entire line
      /xm;

  while ($tu =~ /$fullnode/g) {
    my($id,$type,$attrs) = ($1,$2,$3);

    $node{$id} = { TYPE => $type };
    while ($attrs =~ /$attr \s*/gx) {
      if (exists $node{$id}{$1}) {
        $node{$id}{$1} = [ $node{$id}{$1} ] unless ref $node{$id}{$1};
        push @{ $node{$id}{$1} } => $2;
      }
      else {
        $node{$id}{$1} = $2;
      }
    }
  }

  wantarray ? %node : \%node;
}
```

In the main program, we feed the code to g++

```
die usage unless @ARGV >= 1;

my($src,@cflags) = @ARGV;
system("g++", "-c", "-fdump-translation-unit", @cflags, $src) == 0
  or die "$0: g++ failed\n";

my @tu = glob "$src.*.tu";
unless (@tu == 1) {
  die "$0: expected one $src.*.tu file, but found",
      @tu ? ("\n", map("  - $_\n", @tu))
          : " none\n";
}
```

Assuming all went well, we then pluck out the function definitions given in the specified source file.

```
my $node = read_tu @tu;

sub isfunc {
  my($n) = @_;
  $n->{TYPE} eq "function_decl"
             &&
  index($n->{srcp}, "$src:") == 0;
}

sub nameof {
  my($n) = @_;
  return "<undefined>" unless exists $n->{name};
  $n->{name} =~ /^@/
    ? $node->{ $n->{name} }{strg}
    : $n->{name};
}

print "$_\n" for sort
                 map nameof($_),
                 grep isfunc($_),
                 values %$node;
```

Example run:

```
$ ./getfuncs prog.cc -I.
AccounntBalance
AccountRetrivalForm
```

Comment: That's the way to do it.  I think that you should put the ctags way in front, though.

Comment: @Svante Good suggestion! Updated.

Comment: I agree with you. This is clearly a c-based language he's trying to deal with..and it's just too easy to break any regex with some perfectly valid function declarations. Better to use a tool that understands the language.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie qw(:all);

my $function_count = 0;
open my $input, '<', 'function.txt';
while (defined(my $line = <$input>)) {
    chomp($line);

    if (my ($func) = $line =~ /^(?:int64|void|boolean)\s?(.*?)\(/) {
        print qq{Found function "$func"\n};
        $function_count++;
    }
}
close $input;
print "$function_count\n";
```

Revised answer taking into account the function calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie qw(:all);

my $document;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $input, '<', 'function.txt';
    $document = <$input>;
    chomp $document;
    close $input;
}

my $function_count = 0;
while (my ($func) = $document =~ /(?:int64|void|boolean)\s?(.*?)\(.*?\)\s*\{/gs)) {
    print qq{Found function "$func"\n};
    $function_count++;
}

print "$function_count\n";
```

Comment: No need to chomp the line I think because you are not matching against the end of the line.

Comment: Very true, just added the chomp as a force of habit.

Comment: Thanks.But the above code returns the count for even the function call.. int64 AccounntBalance(char *reg12,char *refid,char **id);