# Trouble reading file in array by line number in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am working with two files, so as I loop through one I need to look through part of another one, and the information I encounter in it will be sequential. So I thought the best way would be to keep track of the line number: 


`open(PARSED, "< file.txt") or die$!;

my @parsedFile = < PARSED >;

my $line = 0;

my $size = @parsedFile;

# This next part is in a loop, but the only important thing is this next line

print $parsedFile[$line];`

Even as the value of $line increases, it prints nothing but if I do the following there is no problem:


`foreach (@parsedFile){
    print $_;
}`


I have even tried a number of variations of trying to pull individual lines from @parsedFile but with no luck.

Comment: Am I missing something? By your example, `@parsedFile` only contains the string `file.txt`. Could you provide more info, so we can help you?

Comment: My mistake, fixed it, I was just hand copying a part of my program.

Comment: Your posted example prints first line of file just fine... I only had to put ; after <PARSED>...

Comment: It's a very good idea to use 3 argument open with lexical filehandles.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<>` is an incredibly picky operator that does two very different things based solely on precise syntax of what's in the brackets.  `< PARSED >` (with the extra spaces) is glob("PARSED"), not readline(PARSED), so your array is just getting the single string "PARSED".

(Assuming your posted code is accurate; it really helps if you copy and paste your actual not-working code, not re-type parts of it; it helps even more if your copy-and-pasted code can be run exactly as is to demonstrate your problem.)

Note that:

```
use warnings;
open(PARSED, "< filename") or die $!;
my @lines = < PARSED >;
```

will give you a warning that PARSED is used only once, a big clue that the `<>` isn't doing what you think.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the pickiness. still doesn't explain why it's supposedly working in a `foreach` loop though...

Comment: Thank you. I just rewrote all things related to that file and got it to work.

Comment: @goreSplatter: what is going wrong there is some nuance we don't have available for us to see, e.g. multiple `my @parsedFile`, misspellings, etc.

Comment: One more question, if you do something like my @lines = <PARSED>, can you no longer use <PARSED>? Just to test it, afterwards I did while(<PARSED>) but it seems to not enter this loop.

Comment: @NCH: you can use PARSED again, but it has reached the end of the file, so to read it again from the beginning you'd need to do `seek(PARSED,0,0)` first.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem was fixed by ysth, but if the files aren't huge (you are reading them into memory, so I'm guessing not), why not use [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) instead of all those shenanigans?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Tie::File;

tie my @parsedFile, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "Error: $!";

my $line = 0;
print $parsedFile[$line];
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for later use. The files I am using aren't too large.

Comment: alternatively, if the only use of the array is to iterate over it, why read the whole file in?

Comment: Well, I am checking for particular matches in the file and then I want to keep that string, and I don't know where the match will be.

Answer (score 0):

To load the file lines in an array you need to open the file first:

```
open F,'<','file.txt' or die;
my @parsedFile = <F>;
```

The way you are doing it results in array `parsedFile` which contains only one element `"file.txt"` which is the name of the file.