# Different ways of opening file in perl

Tags: perl, file

I have seen that in perl sometimes to open a file for writing they use:

```
open(my $file_handle, ">$file_name");
```

And sometimes:

```
open(FILE_HANDLE, ">$file_name");
```

What is the difference?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [Why is three-argument open calls with lexical filehandles a Perl best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first method you showed is the newer, and usually favorable method.  It uses lexical filehandles (filehandles that are lexically scoped).  The second method uses package-global typeglob filehandles.  Their scoping is broader.  Modern Perl programs usually use the 'my' version, unless they have a good reason not to.

You ought to have a look at [perlopentut (from the Perl documentation)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html), and [perlfunc -f open (from the Perl POD)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).  Those two resources give you a lot of good information.  While you're there, look up the three argument version of open, as well as error checking.  A really good way to open a file nowadays is:

```
open my $file_handle, '>', $filename or die $!;
```