# How to append to a file?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to append some text to the end of a file in Mac OSX having a .conf extension. I am using the following code to do that:

```
open NEW , ">>$self->{natConf}";
print NEW "$hostPort = $vmIP";
```

where

```
$self->{natConf} = \Library\Preferences\VMware Fusion\vmnet8\nat.conf
```

So basically this is a .conf file. And even though its not returning any error, but it is not appending anything to the end of the file. I checked all the permissions, and read-write privilege has been provided. Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: that looks like a windows path to me, have you tried it with `/` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `use strict` and `use warnings`. This would have thrown errors and warnings for your code.

On Mac OS the delimiter in a path is `/` like in other unix-like systems not `\`.
To asign a string to a variable use quotation marks.
Do not use `open(2)` but `open(3)` (the arrow operator does not work in your usage of open anyway) and it is considered bad practice to use bareword filehandlers.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# your code here

$self->{natConf} = '/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf';

# more code here

open my $fh, '>>', $self->{natConf} or die "open failed: $!\n";
print $fh "$hostPort = $vmIP";
close $fh;

# rest of code here
```

Comment: Good answer. It might be worth explaining the change to using a lexical file handle though.

Comment: You are right. It was issued in this question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the '/' problem, its working now. I am still in the transition period between Windows and Mac, it sucks :(

Comment: That should almost certainly be `print $fh "$hostPor = $vmIP\n";` (i.e., you want a trialing newline).

Comment: it would be worth either testing the result of `open` by writing `open my $fh, '>>', $self->{natConf} or die "cannot open $self->{natConf}: $!;` or, even simpler, adding `use autodie qw(open);` at the top of the code, which will do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Suffering from buffering? Call `close NEW` when you are done writing to it, or call `(*NEW)->autoflush(1)` on it after you open it to force Perl to flush the output after every print.

Also check the return values of the `open` and `print` calls. If either of these functions fail, they will return false and set the `$!` variable.

And I second the recommendation about using `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, although my issue was solved even without it, but this is good advice.