# Why is command dying in the script but not when I execute it outside the script?

Tags: perl

I'm using ActivePerl 5.12.4 on Windows 7.  I have this in my script …

```
my $cmd = "ant -Dbuildtarget=$env -Dmodule=\"$module\" -Dproject=$project -Dnolabel=true checkout-selenium-tests";
print "cmd: $cmd\n"; 
open(F, $cmd) or die "Failed to execute: $!";
while (<F>) {
    print;
}
```

Sadly, my script dies at the "open" command with the failure:

```
Failed to execute: Invalid argument at run_single_folder.pl line 17.
```

I don't know what's wrong.  When I print out the command that's executed, I can execute that command normally in the command window and it runs fine.  How can I figure out why executing the command in the Perl script is dying when it is succeeding on the command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start a subprocess with a call to `open()` and capture its output you need to use a `|` after the command, or perl will think you want to open a file.

Comment: Better, use the three-argument version of open: `open(F, '-|', $cmd)`

Comment: Yeah, the three argument form of `open` is considered best practice. Also, using a scalar to hold your filehandle e.g. `open (my $fh, '-|', $cmd)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Comment: The list of obsolete but persistent idioms goes on and on. ;)

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström, You're cargo culting. Three arg offers an advantage over two args for file names, but that's not the case for pipes. Ideally, you'd use 4+ args for pipes to avoid the shell.

Comment: Rock on.  The three argument method with the '-|' worked great for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Perl it's a pipe using "`|`".

```
open(my $PIPE, "foo |")   # Get output from foo

open(my $PIPE, "| foo")   # Send input to foo
```

Since you don't need the shell, let's avoid it but using the multi-arg version. For one thing, it saves you from converting `$env`, `$module` and `$project` to shell literals (like you tried to do with `$module`).

```
my @cmd = (
   ant => (
      "-Dbuildtarget=$env",
      "-Dmodule=$module",
      "-Dproject=$project",
      "-Dnolabel=true",
      "checkout-selenium-tests",
   )
);

open(my $PIPE, '-|', @cmd) or die "Failed to execute: $!";
while (<$PIPE>) {
   print;
}
```