# Issues of saving an array into a plain text file

Tags: perl

I have built an array, such as A = [a1,a2,...aN]. How to save this array into a data file, with each element to be placed at one row. In other words, for the array A, the file should look like

```
a1
a2
a3
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very simple (this is assuming, of course, that your array is explicitly specified as an array data structure, which your question doesn't quite make clear):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @a = (1, 2, 3); # The array we want to save

# Open a file named "output.txt"; die if there's an error
open my $fh, '>', "output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";

# Loop over the array
foreach (@a)
{
    print $fh "$_\n"; # Print each entry in our array to the file
}
close $fh; # Not necessary, but nice to do
```

The above script will write the following to "output.txt":

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Nowadays you should be using the 3-argument form of 'open'. Also you would be better putting your filehandle into a lexical, e.g. "open my $file, '>', 'output.txt' ..."

Comment: @hochgurgler +1 The reason can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Comment: @hochgurgler Thanks for the info. I had no idea that a 3-argument form existed, let along that it was a best practice!

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want the `foreach` loop, you can do this:

> ```
> print $fh join ("\n", @a);
> ```

Comment: Your `map` is redundant.

Comment: @Sobrique: indeed, since the 'join' builtin is already 'loopy'. I've removed it, and ditched the parentheses round join's arguments (pending review).