# perl check file contents and match username

Tags: perl

I am new to perl programming.  I have a scenario where a username is entered in a file, lets say `info.log`.  So, now I want to check whether this username is present in the file contents or not

```
 $user = $ENV{USER};
 open (READ_USER_INFO_LOG, "info.log") || die("-E- Unable to open \"info.log\n");
          @content = <READ_USER_INFO_LOG>;
          close READ_USER_INFO_LOG;
          foreach $line(@content)
          {
             if($line has $user)
             {
                  print "Usenrmae found";
                   break;
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $user = $ENV{USER};
 open (READ_USER_INFO_LOG, "info.log") || die("-E- Unable to open \"info.log\n");
          @content = <READ_USER_INFO_LOG>;
          close READ_USER_INFO_LOG;
          foreach $line(@content)
          {
             if($line =~ /$user/)
             {
                  print "Usenrmae found";
                   break;
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 7):

Okay, a few things:

1. Always, always, **always** [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  Each and every single time.
2. [Bareword filehandles are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice).  Use a three argument open:
   `open(my $read_user_info_log,"<","info.log") or die "-E- Unable to open \"info.log\"\n";`
3. `$line has $user` doesn't mean anything.  Instead, you can check each line via a regular expression:  `if($line=~/$user/){...}`
4. Perl's equivalent of `break` is [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).
5. You may also want to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the lines of your file to remove the trailing end of line characters:
   `chomp(my @content=<$read_user_info_log>);`

Honestly, I'd recommend reading the (newly released) sixth edition of [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do?green=E0942334-A3D4-53B9-9720-C8AA1518031A&cmp=af-mybuy-0636920018452.IP).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to change the line:

```
 if($line has $user)
```

to

```
 if ($line =~ /$user/)
```

This way, a regular expression will search the line for `$user` anywhere within it.