# cleaner method to open and close filehandles dynamically?

Tags: perl

I have an array of entries which will be search in a large file, each entry is then written to its own output file. the array varies based on certain conditions and therefore has to be dynamic.

Here is my example `array`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ("ABC",
             "DEF",
             "GHI",
             "JKL",
             "MNO",
             "PQR"
             );
```

So I created a loop to open create a filehandle for each of the entries. run my commands, then a loop again to close the filehandles.

```
foreach my $handle(@array) {
        my $output = "OUTPUT_$handle.txt";
           open ($handle, '>', $output) or die "unable to open file $!";
}

#... write to files and do some other fancy stuff ...

foreach $handle(@array) {
           close $handle;
    }
```

Which will create: `OUTPUT_ABC.txt` `OUTPUT_DEF.txt`.. etc.

So my question: It seems to feel very awkward for me to have to loop through opening each and loop closing each handle, is there a more elegant method to open and close file handles dynamically?

Comment: Use lexical filehandles, they close when they go out of scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand your concern, but you could make it more concise by using statement modifiers. Also, using the `autodie` pragma removes the need to check the status of each operation

```
use autodie;

open $_, '>', "OUTPUT_$_.txt" for @array;

...

close for @array;
```

Note that, if you wrap the code that uses the file handles in `@array` in a block `{ ... }`, then they will be closed implicitly when they go out of scope. You just need to make sure that the declaration `my @array` (a terrible identifier, by the way) is within the block.

Comment: It is not so much a concern, might just be my OCD. This is what I meant with more elegant. Thank you

Comment: Are those lexical filehandles or old-style handles? Because `@array` is an array of strings, not file handles so my gut feeling is that those won't close when they go out of scope.

Comment: @el.pescado: They use lexical array elements, so they are lexical handles. The original contents of the array are irrelevant except for building the file name string. The call to `open` overwrites each array element with the new file handle reference.

Comment: @Borodin Are you sure? `print Dumper \@array;` indicates otherwise. `system("ls -l /proc/$$/fd");` shows that files are still open.

Comment: OK, found it. *"If FILEHANDLE is an **undefined** scalar variable (or array or hash element), a new filehandle is autovivified, meaning that the variable is assigned a reference to a newly allocated anonymous filehandle. Otherwise if FILEHANDLE is an expression, its value is the real filehandle. (This is considered a symbolic reference, so use strict "refs" should not be in effect.)"*. [(perldoc open)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) So that passing lexical value to `open` is not sufficient - it has to be undefined. This code opens `ABC`, `DEF` etc old-style file handles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lexical filehandles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-autovivified-filehandles-a-perl-best-pract):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw/ABC DEF/;

{
    my %fh = map { open my $fh, ">", "OUTPUT_$_.txt"; $_ => $fh } @array;
    print {$fh{ABC}} "Something...";
}
# Here your filehandles in %fh will be closed already.
```