# How do I evaluate shell variables in a string?

Tags: perl

In my Perl script I get strings of file paths that may contain environment variables, e.g. `$FONTS/test.ttf` or `$TMP/file.txt`.

I now want to open those files like this:

```
open my $handle, "<$filename" or die $!;
```

How can I now expand the environment variables prior to the open call, as e.g. the bash shell would do?

Comment: you really want to use a 3 arg open here to prevent a security vulnerability.

Comment: Might as well provide links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318789/whats-the-best-way-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the environmental variables are set, you can use a simple substitution:

```
$filename =~ s/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g;
```

Comment: Neat and succinct - and, as ever, error processing will screw it up.  Specifically, if one of the environment variables referenced is not set, you will at best get an unexpected path; you may also get warnings about accessing undefined variables from Perl.  Although there are other shell notations (like `${TMP}`), they are seldom used in contexts where that will be a problem.

Comment: @Jonathan, the standard behavior for bash is to substitute the empty string for a missing variable, so this code does handle that error condition in the way the OP asked. I agree on the alternate shell notations I use `${FOO:?}` quite a lot in scripts to force bash to throw errors on unset variables.

Comment: I updated this to `s/\$\{?(\w+)\}?/$ENV{$1}/` to support the alternate curly brace format.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do this:

```
$filename =~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/g;
$filename =~ s/\$(\w+)/$ENV{$1}/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following is considerably more verbose, but it
seems to correctly handle both `$FOO` and `${FOO}` syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
print(" GIVEN: <$filename>\n");
my $expanded = '';
my @parts = split(/(\$\w+)|(\${\w+})/, $filename);
foreach my $seg (@parts)
  {
    next if (not defined($seg));
    $seg = ($ENV{$1} || '')  if ($seg =~ m/\${?(\w+)}?/);
    $expanded .= $seg;
  }

print("IS NOW: <$expanded>\n");
print(`echo "  ECHO: <$filename>"`);  # How the shell did it.
```

Here's a sample run...

```
$ ./expand '$TERM ---${TERM}--- ===${FOO}=== $FOO'
 GIVEN: <$TERM ---${TERM}--- ===${FOO}=== $FOO>
IS NOW: <xterm-color ---xterm-color--- ====== >
  ECHO: <xterm-color ---xterm-color--- ====== >
$
```

In this version, undefined symbols are replace with an empty string,
like the shell.  But in my apps I'd rather leave the unexpanded
invalid symbol in place making it easier to see what went wrong.
Also, if you screw up your bracket matching, the shell will 
give you a "bad substitution" error, but here we'll just return 
the string with the broken symbol still in place.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but you are wrong.

to work in perl with SHELL variables, the correct syntax is : $ENV{variable}

example with a colored GCC output function :

```
n=$(tput setaf 0)
r=$(tput setaf 1)
g=$(tput setaf 2)
y=$(tput setaf 3)
b=$(tput setaf 4)
m=$(tput setaf 5)
c=$(tput setaf 6)
w=$(tput setaf 7)
N=$(tput setaf 8)
R=$(tput setaf 9)
G=$(tput setaf 10)
Y=$(tput setaf 11)
B=$(tput setaf 12)
M=$(tput setaf 13)
C=$(tput setaf 14)
W=$(tput setaf 15)
END=$(tput sgr0)

colorgcc()
    {
    perl -wln -M'Term::ANSIColor' -e '
    m/not found$/ and print "$ENV{N}$`$ENV{END}", "$&", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/found$/ and print "$ENV{N}$`${g}", "$&", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/yes$/ and print "$ENV{N}$`${g}", "$&", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/no$/ and print "$ENV{N}$`$ENV{END}", "$&", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/undefined reference to/i and print "$ENV{r}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/ Error |error:/i and print "$ENV{r}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/ Warning |warning:/i and print "$ENV{y}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/nsinstall / and print "$ENV{c}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/Linking |\.a\b/ and print "$ENV{C}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    m/Building|gcc|g\+\+|\bCC\b|\bcc\b/ and print "$ENV{N}", "$_", "$ENV{END}"
    or
    print; '
    }
```