# Problems reading a binary file with ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, binaryfiles, activestate

I'm trying to read a binary file with the following code:

```
open(F, "<$file") || die "Can't read $file: $!\n";
binmode(F);
$data = <F>;
close F;

open (D,">debug.txt");
binmode(D);
print D $data;
close D;
```

The input file is 16M; the debug.txt is only about 400k.  When I look at debug.txt in emacs, the last two chars are ^A^C (SOH and ETX chars, according to notepad++) although that same pattern is present in the debug.txt.  The next line in the file does have a ^O (SI) char, and I think that's the first occurrence of that particular character.

How can I read in this entire file?

Comment: $data = <F>; gets  $data = do { undef $/; <F> };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **really** want to read the whole file at once, use slurp mode. Slurp mode can be turned on by setting `$/` (which is the input record separator) to `undef`. This is best done in a separate block so you don't mess up `$/` for other code.

```
my $data;
{
    open my $input_handle, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file for reading: $!\n";
    binmode $input_handle;
    local $/;
    $data = <$input_handle>;
    close $input_handle;
}

open $output_handle, '>', 'debug.txt' or die "Cannot open debug.txt for writing: $!\n";
binmode $output_handle;
print {$output_handle} $data;
close $output_handle;
```

Use `my $data` for a lexical and `our $data` for a global variable.

Comment: Edited in order to promote modern practices, see rationale at [Why is three-argument open calls with lexical filehandles a Perl best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice) and [What’s the best way to open and read a file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318789/whats-the-best-way-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-perl).

Comment: @daxim - I wanted to suggest that check, but I felt it was the OP's own responsibility... :)

Comment: We can't teach without leading with good role models and eradicating outdated code. :)

Comment: I sense I've just been called outdated :)  In any case, the solution here was to undef $/.  (This solution still fails to write out the complete file to debug.txt, but this the goal was to get all my data into $data, it's good enough for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[TIMTOWTDI](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?TIMTOWTDI).

[`File::Slurp`](http://p3rl.org/File::Slurp) is the shortest way to express what you want to achieve. It also has built-in error checking.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my $data = read_file($file, binmode => ':raw');
write_file('debug.txt', {binmode => ':raw'}, $data);
```

---

The [`IO::File` API](http://p3rl.org/IO::File) solves the global variable `$/` problem in a more elegant fashion.

```
use IO::File qw();
my $data;
{
    my $input_handle = IO::File->new($file, 'r') or die "could not open $file for reading: $!";
    $input_handle->binmode;
    $input_handle->input_record_separator(undef);
    $data = $input_handle->getline;
}
{
    my $output_handle = IO::File->new('debug.txt', 'w') or die "could not open debug.txt for writing: $!";
    $output_handle->binmode;
    $output_handle->print($data);
}
```

Comment: Not so much concerned with elegance - this is a quick & dirty solution.  But thanks for the education.

Comment: In the second example why are you localising the code in blocks?

Comment: When a handle variable goes out of scope, the attached file descriptor it is closed automatically. A naked block is the most straightforward way to create such a scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is about using slurp mode or not, but about correctly handling binary files.

instead of

```
$data = <F>;
```

you should do

```
read(F, $buffer, 1024);
```

This will only read 1024 bytes, so you have to increase the buffer or read the whole file part by part using a loop.