# Best way to properly read from a file, process input and write the output to a second file

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 open (FILE, 'data.txt');
 while (<FILE>) {

 ($ip,$me,$id) = split(" ");

 print "Ip: $ip\n";

 open(F,'>ip.txt') || die $!;

  print F  "$ip \n" ;

close(F);

 print "me: $me\n";
  print "ID: $id\n";
 print "---------\n";
 }
 close (FILE);
 exit;
```

I want perl to `print`  output within newlines in the file to which it is writing. How can I check if  a line in the input file is null or not.

I would like the output to look like this (in `ip.txt`):

```
123.121.121.0
545.45.45.45 
..
..
etc
```

Comment: Please indent your code.  Why are you truncating the file `ip.txt` for every line you read?  Please learn about `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and avoid bareword file handles; that's so early-90s style Perl — use `my $file = "data.txt"; open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open file $file for reading";` (also error checking the open operation).

Answer (score 2):

Your filehandle of the ip.txt is opened for every row in your data.txt. That's horrible and overwrites all content. You open it for writing (`>`), not appending (`>>`). Here is a better code. Please use the 3-argument `open` and don't use barewords as filehandles.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = 'data.txt'
my $ip_file = 'ip.txt';
open( my $FILE, '<',$file ) || die "Can't open $file for reading $!";
open( my $F, '>',$ip_file ) || die "Can't open $ip_file for writing $!";
while ( my $line = <$FILE> ) {

  my ( $ip, $me, $id ) = split( " ", $line );
  print "Ip: $ip\n";
  print $F "$ip \n";
  print "me: $me\n";
  print "ID: $id\n";
  print "---------\n";
}
close ($F);
close( $FILE );
```

Comment: You should die on failing to open the input file, too, shouldn't you?

Comment: Its from `Best Practices`. Also seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318789/whats-the-best-way-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-perl)

Comment: Okay, to make it more specific. `Best Practices`, Chapter 10. But he use `croak`. I prefer that way more than `die`, too.

Comment: You should `die` on closing a file. If it's was an input file, you will see any read errors. If it was an output file, closing first prints anything remaining in the buffer, then closes; and you should print an errors.

Comment: Croak is specifically for a package when you want to make sure that the caller gives the error and not the method. Otherwise, you can use die. Even better, use `autodie;` and then you don't need `die` or `croak`.