# How to read a .conf file in Perl

Tags: perl

I just created a text `test.conf` file with some information. How can I read it on Perl?
I am new to Perl and I am not sue would will I need to do.
I tried  the following:

```
C:\Perl\Perl_Project>perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
open (MYFILE, 'test.conf'); 
while (<MYFILE>) 
{ chomp; print "$_\n"; } 
close (MYFILE);
```

I tried installing Perl on my laptop that has Windows 7 OS, and using command line.

Comment: That's a lot to stick on the command line.  Put the Perl program you have up there in a file and run it using `c:\> perl MyPerlProgram.pl`.  Also, if this is Windows, the shebang line isn't really doing anything for you.

Comment: its a test.conf file that I created ..... its not test.pl
I am afraid I didn't get that.

Comment: Check out https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny

Comment: What is your program doing that makes you think it's not working? Have you considered adding an `or die $!` to your `open()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to open and read a file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318789/whats-the-best-way-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-perl)

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Your program, as it stands, doesn't do anything very useful. The extension `.conf` suggests that you might want to do something else with the information in that file, other than just printing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using command line, write your program in a file (you can use any editor to write your program, I would suggest use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and save as `myprogram.pl` in the same directory where you have your `.conf` file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "test.conf" or die $!;
while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
} 
close $fh;
```

Now open a command prompt and go to the same path where you have your both file `myprogram.pl` and `test.conf` file and execute your program by typing this:

```
perl myprogram.pl
```

---

You can give full path of your input file inside program and can run your program from any path from command prompt by giving full path of your program:

```
perl path\to\myprogram.pl
```

**Side note:** Always use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your program and to open file always use lexical filehandle with three arguments with error handling.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment more than an answer, as I believe @serenesat has given you everything you need to execute your program.

When you do "command line" Perl, it's typically stuff that is relatively brief or trivial, such as:

```
perl -e "print 2 ** 16"
```

Anything that goes beyond a few lines, and you're probably better off putting that in a file and having Perl run the file.  You certainly **can** put larger programs on the command line, but when it comes to going back in and editing lines, it becomes more of a hassle than a shortcut.

Also, for what it's worth the `-n` and `-p` parameters allow you to process the contents of a stream, meaning you could do something like this:

```
perl -ne "print if /oracle/i" test.conf
```